# how to make awk extract text in xml with a tag that includes quotation marks

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, xml

Without quotes, it works fine.

If the line in cust.xml is : `\<span style=CustomerId/>999\</CustomerId> <br>`

```
$ awk -F "[><]" '/span style=CustomerId/{print $3}' cust.xml    # prints 999
```

But what if the xml tag has quotes in it?

If the line in cust.xml is : `\<span style="Cust"/>999\</cust>`

```
$ awk -F "[><]" '/span style=”Cust”/{print $3}' cust.xml  # nothing prints
```

Escaping with \ does not work:

```
$ awk -F "[><]" '/span style=\”Cust\”/{print $3}' cust.xml # same
```

Designating as a string does not work either:

```
$ awk -F "[><]" '/$’span style=”Cust”’/{print $3}' cust.xml # same
```

Comment: Your escaped version fails because it uses unicode ”smart quotes” whereas your text has plain ASCII quotes

Comment: Thank you, steeldriver.  With that fix, I was able to get this first line to work (escaping was not necessary)

Comment: ... while using `awk` might seem like a good idea, imho you really should be using a proper XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`

Comment: I like that xmlstartlet is available on Ubuntu Snap Store and that you have pointed that one out because there a many matches to search term xml